# Linq to EF with Sqlite - Can't Search String (string.contains)

Tags: sqlite

I am building a winforms  desktop application and the app DB is Sqlite.
I am using Linq to Entities with the [Sqlite ADO.NET provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

In my app I need to search a string inside a text column. 
Example ("IsNotEmpty" is my extension method for !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)):

```
        if (param.FirstName.IsNotEmpty())
        {
            selectedCustomers = selectedCustomers.Where(c => (c.firstName.Contains(param.FirstName)));
        }
        if (param.LastName.IsNotEmpty())
        {
            selectedCustomers = selectedCustomers.Where(c => c.lastName.Contains(param.LastName));
        }
```

The problem is that this query is being translated to CHARINDEX SQL function and Sqlite doesn't support it.

When I am switching to IndexOf(string) function ([as suggested here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1715/8544.aspx#8544)) the query is being translated to CHARINDEX too.

When I am switching to IndexOf(string, index) I  receive the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any idea? Should I switch to Access?

Comment: Did you try to use IsNullOrEmpty()? :)

Comment: yes, but how this is related?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use .NET functions in LINQ to Entities its because of security, e.g. `IndexOf()` may do lot of other things than just checking the string.

Use Entity SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738683.aspx instead.